# Leaks in following case

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

I am checking leaks for my code... Using Run performance tools named "Leak" on my simulator..

I am getting all leaks in the following lines of AVAudioPlayer

```
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

Here is the code...

```
NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"song.mp3"]]];
NSError *err = nil;
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&err];

[file release];
player.numberOfLoops = 0;
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];   //Here is the leak 
player.volume=1.0;
isPlaying=YES;
[player play];
```

Please help
Note -- i am releasing the player later....

```
[player stop];

    [player release];
```

I am checking this on simulator .......should i check it on device.....?
if yes please tell me how ?.....should i need to use some other leak checking tool

Comment: Do you invoke [player stop] somewhere? It stops the playback and undoes the setup needed for playback.

Comment: Do you stop / release the player in the same method as you create them? You need to stop / release each player you create and you cannot defer that to the dealloc method if you create the player multiple times during the lifetime of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this blog for fixes to remove leaks in AVAudioPlayer:
http://blog.zincroe.com/2009/06/avaudioplayer-memory-leak/